# A320neo family IATA codes

Tags: iata

I'm about to ask a question that's already been asked but that wasn't answered. I was torn between opening a thread thats many months old or posting a new thread. I apologize if I picked the wrong option.

Previous thread: [What is the IATA code for the A320neo family?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27080/what-is-the-iata-code-for-the-a320neo-family)

What are the IATA codes for the A320neo family?
According Lufthansa, A320neo (ICAO: A20N) is 32V. But that's all that I know.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Please don't ask a question that has already been asked. If there are no good answers already, then the best thing to do is to upvote the original question to attract more attention. You might like to take the [tour] if you aren't familiar with his this site works.

Comment: @Pondlife Vote up is 15 rep, and set bounties is 75 rep (and certainly wouldn't be meaningful below 51 rep, anyway, since the least you can bounty off is 50...). I've found that a *constructive* edit to an old post (a question or any of its answers, if any) can often draw renewed attention to it as well, but one has to be careful in doing so to not change intent.